Losing custom theme for XamCheckEditor
in my xaml.cs file I have this:
public RatesPage(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IThemeSelectorService themeSelectorService)
{
    scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    RatesViewModel viewModel = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RatesViewModel>();

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    themeSelectorService.SetInfragisticsTheme(LayoutRoot);

    Unloaded += RatesPage_Unloaded;
}

the theme selector service sets the colour of the page based on whether the user has selected dark theme or light theme. In the xaml itself I have this:
                    <igWPF:Field Column="4" Name="Included" Label="Included" Width="150" AllowEdit="true">
                        <igWPF:Field.Settings>
                            <igWPF:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igWPF:XamCheckEditor}" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}" LabelClickAction="Nothing">
                                <igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:XamCheckEditor}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Record.DataItem.CanEditRatePart, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igWPF:FieldSettings>
                        </igWPF:Field.Settings>
                    </igWPF:Field>

but for some reason having this:
                                <igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:XamCheckEditor}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Record.DataItem.CanEditRatePart, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>

causes the check editor to lose the theme style and just go back to default setting and i'm not sure how to get it preserve the theme.
